# Getting error for reader and writer accessor method of Moose in perl

Tags: perl, moose

I'm trying to use Moose `reader` and `writer` for setting and getting a value.

The following is `employee.pm`:

```
package employee;
use Moose;

has 'firstName' => (is => 'ro' , isa => 'Str' , required => 1);

has 'salary' => (is => 'rw',
         isa => 'Str',
         writer => 'set_slalary',
         reader => 'get_salary',
         );

has 'department' => (is => 'rw' , default => 'support' );
has 'age' => (is => 'ro' , isa=> 'Str');

no Moose;
__PACKAGE__->meta->make_immutable;
1;
```

The following is my script `1.pl` (which uses the above module):

```
use employee;
use strict;
use warnings;

my $emp = employee->new(firstName => 'Tom' , salary => 50000 , department => 'R&D' , age => '27');

$emp->set_salary(100000);

print $emp->firstName, " works in ", $emp->department, " and his salary is ",  $emp->get_salary() , " and age is ", $emp->age ,"\n" ;
```

In the script, I'm trying to update the `salary` attribute to `100000`. 
I'm getting the following error:

```
Can't locate object method "set_salary" via package "employee" at 1.pl line 7
```

If I comment the line `$emp->set_salary(100000);` in `1.pl`, then I get proper output (without the updated value for the `salary` attribute, obviously).

```
Tom works in R&D and his salary is 50000 and age is 27
```

In `employee.pm`, I have given read and write permission for `salary` attribute. Can anyone suggest where I am going wrong? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/159833/discussion-between-hobbs-and-ikegami).

Comment: You´re presuming that exists some "automatic" method generator. This is not how Moose works! Please, read the docs!

https://www.google.com.br/search?q=metacpan+%2B+Moose&oq=metacpan+%2B+Moose&aqs=chrome..69i57j69i64.3064j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8

Answer (score 0):

You misspelled `set_salary`.

```
writer => 'set_slalary'
```

should be

```
writer => 'set_salary'
```

---

Note that

```
is => 'rw'
```

is just another way of writing

```
accessor => 'salary'
```

Usually. `is` is unreliable when `reader`, `writer` and/or `accessor` are also provided for the same attribute. For example, `is` is sometimes ignored when `reader`, `writer` and/or `accessor` are also provided for the same attribute. (Demonstration below.) This is the case for your program.

As such, it's a bad idea to mix `is` with `reader`/`writer`/`accessor`. Use one style or the other, but not both for any given attribute. In your case, you should get rid of useless `is => 'rw'`.

---

Demonstration of `is=>'rw'`+`reader`+`writer` bug:

`Class.pm`:

```
package Class;

use Moose;

has attr1 => (
   is => 'rw',
   default => 'val1',
);

has attr2 => (
   is => 'rw',
   reader => 'get_attr2',
   writer => 'set_attr2',
   default => 'val2',
);

1;
```

`a.pl`:

```
use feature qw( say );

use FindBin qw( $RealBin );
use lib $RealBin;

use Class;

my $o = Class->new();
say $o->attr1();
say $o->attr2();
```

Output:

```
val1
Can't locate object method "attr2" via package "Class" at a.pl line 10.
```